# Can't sync with git, Unable to write data to the transport connection

Tags: git, plasticscm

(https://i.stack.imgur.com/aNjRK.png)

I was trying to sync with Github, then I got this error at the end.
It always stops after 2.01GB. I have enough git lfs data packs.

Any workaround for this would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

What is your Plastic version? We released time ago this task (the problem seems to be GitHub is declining the operation).

[Bug] 8.0.16.3136
GitSync: The rejected references (if they existed) were not always properly printed after a sync operation This could happen pushing big packages (>500 MB) with hundreds of references. Instead of printing the failed references, the sync command just failed with the error 'Stream terminated early'.

Remarks: Pushing a Plastic repo to GitHub through the 'cm sync' command will fail if the repo contains some file bigger than 100 MB. The error returned by GitHub is 'pre-receive hook declined'. This happens due to the GitHub disk quota policies: https://help.github.com/en/articles/what-is-my-disk-quota